# Split the [opera] tag into [opera-presto] and [opera-blink] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation, tag-creation-request

There is currently an [opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera) tag that is used in any questions related to the (desktop version of the) [Opera](http://www.opera.com) browser.

In mid-2013, Opera discontinued actively developing the **Presto-based version** (Presto being the layout engine developed by Opera in 2003 and used up until version 12.x) and switched to a **Blink-based version** (Blink being the Webkit-forked layout engine used by Chrome and Opera from version 15 onwards - versions 13-14 were never publicly released). This switch represents a major change in the browser's history; so much so that most questions/answers that apply to one version do not apply to the other. All the features that had been developed as part of the Presto-based version were gone and Opera 15 was initially pretty much a re-branded version of Chrome without much at all in terms of functionality. Dragonfly, Opera-Presto's inspector/debugger ([dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dragonfly), [opera-dragonfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-dragonfly)) was not available in the Opera-Blink, mouse gestures were gone, the customisability was gone, etc. Slowly, some of these features were/are being brought back as Opera-Blink matured, but vast differences remain.

I've seen several questions recently where the poster left out version information that is critical to correctly answering the question because of those very differences. For instance, I had to [ask for clarification here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436589/opera-default-page-website-links-with-logo/26436663#comment41526645_26436663) and received a response, but [my clarification request here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650087/google-map-opera#comment41941085_26650087) didn't get a response and the question and single answer have both stalled with zero upvotes because it's not clear what the question is about.

There are already tags for [opera-mini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-mini) and [opera-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-mobile), but I think it would make lots of sense and help clarify new questions if those asking about the desktop version could specify which layout engine their question refers to. I don't have the rep to create tags (and wouldn't want to do so without asking for community input first), but would suggest that two new tags be added:

- [opera-presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-presto) - for questions relating to the older desktop version, and
- [opera-blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-blink) - for questions relating to the newer desktop version.

The old [opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera) tag could be kept for questions already asked that fall into neither subcategory (though I can't think of any off-hand), or (which would obviously require a bit more work), the [opera-presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-presto) tag could replace it for all older questions while those asked since mid-2013 would have to be checked to see which one applies. Either way would help to eliminate some of the confusion.

Comment: Hm, or we just use the [tag:blink] tag for all questions that affect Chrome, Chromium, the new Opera etc…

Comment: @Bergi: That could work, but a) I suspect fewer people will be aware of what "Blink" is (as opposed to WebKit), and b) you'd have to make the assumption that leaving out that tag implies that it's a Presto issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created the two tags, [opera-presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-presto), and [opera-blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-blink). I have also created/edited the descriptions of these two tags plus the generic [opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera) tag so that it should hopefully be clear when to use which.

Unless someone comes up with a better idea, I thought this would be the best way, so that those who subscribe to the generic tag (like me) don't miss out on questions marked *only* with one of the specific ones. Only in cases where I run into the 5-tag limit (and all other tags are relevant) in future will I replace the generic tag with the specific one that applies.

So far, I've only edited one question in each category to add the tag, and have, in both cases, left the generic [opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera) tag in place to avoid confusion. I'm hoping to gradually increase the count for each as I find the time to edit existing questions that only apply to one of the two. I'll keep my fingers crossed that this separation makes sense to and will be adopted by the community as well as posters of new Opera-related questions.

Comment: If you're feeling particularly evil, you could propose [opera-blink] as a synonym of [google-chrome] ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: Mwahaha... _yeees_... no, wait, uhm, on second thought, maybe better not. I'll leave that to someone who can afford to get down-voted lots. ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock: On a more serious note (having just read up on tag synonyms a bit), please feel free to make both new tags a synonym of the old one (master) - as far as I can tell, it seems to have been done that way for other "child" tags. I don't have the rep yet to do this myself. Many thanks :-)

Comment: When you make the two new tags synonyms of the old tag, that means questions with either of the new tags will *display* the old tag instead, which means you'll never see either of the specific tags. That would defeat their purpose I think, since the new tags are meant to distinguish questions about either version of Opera.

Comment: @BoltClock: Whoops, ok, scratch that, then. Though I have to say that I'm confused now... looks like I need to read up more to understand synonyms.

Comment: In 2022: `opera-presto` and `opera-blink` have 20 questions between them; `opera` has almost two thousand. Doesn't seem to me like this one accomplished very much.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: agreed. :-/